# Powershell script to get hyperlink addresses on a Powerpoint slide AND the name of each associated Shape object?

Tags: powershell, powerpoint

I have been struggling with something that seems like it should be trivial...

All I want to do in my PowerShell script is *loop thru all the slides in a Powerpoint presentation* (ppt 2016), display all the hyperlinks associated with each slide **AND** the name of the Shape object the hyperlink is associated with.

I have tried two different ways:

1. loop thru all the **Hyperlinks** in the slideshow but I
   **cannot** seem to **get the name** of the associated **shape object**.
2. loop thru all the **Shapes** in the slideshow but I
   **cannot** seem to **get the Address** of the any associated **hyperlink**.

My searches have not yielded anything obvious. From a shape object (slide.shapes) I do not seem to be able to do anything with the 'shape.linkformat.sourcefullname' (typically empty) and from a Hyperlink object (slide.hyperlinks) I do not seem to be able to get to the name of the associated Shape object.

Also, if this matters, note that the show-source-folder structure (many .ppsx files) is a mix of slide-show ages, some going back to Win 7 and PPT 2010.

Here is a simplified code snippet using the list of slide.hyperlinks (as opposed to the list of slide.shapes and digging out the h-link):

```
    $file = "$env:UserProfile\DOcuments\myShow.ppsx"
    Add-Type -AssemblyName Office
    $objPPT = New-Object -ComObject powerpoint.Application
    $ShowPres = $objPPT.Presentations.Open($file, $Null, $Null,[Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState]::msoFalse)
    if ($ShowPres) {
        Foreach ($Slide in $ShowPres.Slides) {
            if ($Slide.HyperLinks) {
                Foreach ($HLink in $Slide.HyperLinks) {
                    Write-Host "[Slide]: $($Slide.SlideNumber), Link: <$($HLink.address)>, Shape Name: ???"
                } #end ea. HyperLink
            } else {
                Write-Host "[No Hyperlink(s)], Slide #: $($Slide.SlideNumber)"
            }
        } #end: loop ea. slide
        $ShowPres.Close()
    } else {
        # empty presentation?
        Write-Host -back Yellow -fore Black " No Presentation FILE: $file"
    }
    $objPPT.Visible = [Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState]::msoTrue
    $objPPT.Quit() 
    $objPPT = $null
    [gc]::collect()
    [gc]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

**Any help/advice/education is much appreciated**.

Comment: Try `$hlink.parent.parent.name`

Comment: @Mike Shepard...I have tried this and only about 5% of the Shape names show associated with each of the HLink addresses on a slide. The 95% that *do not* show the Shape name seem to be hyperlinks assigned to text strings. When the $HLink.address is null, 100% of the Shape names show via $HLink.parent.parent.name. 

So, are there different 'types' of Hyperlinks? Does PPT treat a link different if its a link to an associated slide compared to an image, or another .ppsx file? If the link is associated with a button vs. a text string?

Comment: No idea.  I just created a simple ppt and looked at the objects.  Using `Show-Object` from the PowerShellCookbook module makes it pretty easy to dig around.